# Can we get a local to take us to Gilli M from Gilli T at a time that suites us?

Tags: air-travel, indonesia

We are wanting to get from Gilli Trawangan to Gilli Meno. We also want to be dropped directly at our resort in the north of Gilli Meno.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gili Trawangan to Gili Air/Meno by boat?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50982/gili-trawangan-to-gili-air-meno-by-boat)

Comment: @pnuts What a strange question. Where are places named as such around Seattle?

Comment: @pnuts They're islands. It's theoretically possible that they have airfields and some sort of air service.

Comment: @pnuts Hence _my_ question. Your comment about "Seattle or Indonesia" makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @pnuts For something obvious like that, the proper thing to do is to edit.